# How to add conditions in process.stdin's readable event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdin

Well, I'm trying to pass a simple `if statement` to a `process.stdin` readable stream in NodeJS. But it doesn't seem working. Here's the code :

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if (chunk !== null && chunk == 'foo') {
    process.stdout.write('true\n');
} else if (chunk !== null) {
    process.stdout.write('false\n');
}
```

Does anyone know, what am I doing wrong here? I also tried `chunk == 'foo\n'` but, had no luck. The only time it works is when I set `chunk` value to a number, like `chunk == 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Siam the issue here is that the `chunk` is of `Buffer` type, and not a `string`. You can use `chunk.toString()` to make it a string, and then compare it with `"foo\n"` and it would work

So your code would look something like this:

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if (chunk !== null && chunk.toString() == 'foo\n') {
    process.stdout.write('true\n');
  } else if (chunk !== null) {
    process.stdout.write('false\n');
  }
});
```

**EDIT 1:**

Make sure that you are using compare string same as the input. for e.g in the above case, New line character can be `CRLF` or `\r\n` on windows based systems, while on Unix based systems its `LF` or `\n`. Hence, try using `"foo\r\n"` for comparison, if on windows

Comment: yea I tried this already, but not working. I don't know whats wrong. :(

Comment: It worked for me... Probably some other issue... 
Did you try using "data" event? and not "readable"
Also , what version of node.js are you using?

Comment: yes I did. but same issue with 'data' too. :/ and I'm using ver 7.0.0 of NodeJS.

Comment: can you log the value of chunk.toString (encode it first, using any `escape`  or `encodeURI`)
that would tell you what's difference between the input and the matchString

Comment: on windows system, new line can be `CRLF` or `\r\n` while on unix based systems its `LF` or `\n` .. try using `\r\n` if on windows

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .prompt() ([example](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_tiny_cli)) method